# Parsing JSON array if I don't know array names

Tags: java, android, json

I've got this JSON file. But what to do if I dont know array names (First, Second). How to parse this file in android?
Thanx

```
{
  "First": [
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3",
    "Test4",
    "Test5"
],
 "Second": [
    "Test1",
    "Test2"
] }
```

Comment: You may use Jackson: http://websystique.com/java/json/jackson-convert-java-map-to-from-json/

Comment: @PedroH, thanx for your reply, but I dont need it cause I dont know array names

Comment: You can get it as a map and iterate using the entry set.

Answer (score 0):

JSON you're working with already is an array. So, don't construct an instance of ***JSONObject***; use a ***JSONArray***. This should suffice:

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){                          
    JSONObject e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    String ex = jsonArray.getString("")

}
```

Comment: It's actually a JSONObject with two JSONArrays inside it.